# Capture all multiline text between two know words using regex Python 3

Tags: python, sql, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying capture all the text across multiple lines of text using Python's regex package. The text I have is, as you'll notice it's SQL. Why that's relevant is that I want to capture everything between the "SELECT" phrase and the "FROM" phrase. In the example below I've got 3 items, column1,column2,sum(column3) but I could have many more. 
Also, I only know that I will likely have a `\n` or a `\r` but I don't know if it will be one or more.

```
SELECT
a11.Column1
, a12.Column2
,SUM(Column3)
FROM DB.MyFactTable a11
LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.MyDimTable_1 a12 ON 
(a11.k1 = a12.k1 AND a11.k2 = a12.k2 AND a12.k3 = a11.k3)
LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.MyDimTable_2 a13 ON 
(a11.k1 = a12.k2 AND a11.k4 = a12.k4 AND a12.k5 = a11.k5)
WHERE a11.Column_N IN (X1, X2, X3, X4)
GROUP BY 1,2
```

My regex thus far has been

```
rgx_pat = (?<=SELECT)(\s)*.*\n.*
result = re.findall(rgx_pat,my_sql_above,re.MULTILINE)
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Why not just `SELECT(.*)FROM` with `re.DOTALL`? Or maybe `SELECT(.*?)FROM`, and maybe you want to require some whitespace around the keywords, etc., but whichever one you want, hard to get simpler than that.

Comment: If you have multiple selets in your file the `re.DOTALL` needs to be guareded with a negative lookahead of `SELECT` so in does not capture from first to last (or maybe `(.*?)`) would work as well).

Comment: @PatrickArtner You don't need negative lookahead if you want to switch the greediness, just use `?`.

Comment: Thanks guys for the input. How did I miss that? This was super helpful.

Comment: For novices, or people who just don’t use regex that often and have to refresh themselves each time, `MULTILINE` sure sounds like what you need more than `DOTALL`, until you read the descriptions carefully or play with them in an interactive tester.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is just that you don't know about the [`DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag.

If you're trying to find a bunch of anything including newlines, you don't need to try to figure out a query involving everything-but-newlines plus newlines, just use `DOTALL` and now `.` means anything including newlines.

So:

```
query = '''SELECT
a11.Column1
, a12.Column2
,SUM(Column3)
FROM DB.MyFactTable a11
LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.MyDimTable_1 a12 ON 
(a11.k1 = a12.k1 AND a11.k2 = a12.k2 AND a12.k3 = a11.k3)
LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.MyDimTable_2 a13 ON 
(a11.k1 = a12.k2 AND a11.k4 = a12.k4 AND a12.k5 = a11.k5)
WHERE a11.Column_N IN (X1, X2, X3, X4)
GROUP BY 1,2
'''

rgx_pat = re.compile(r'SELECT\s(.*?)\sFROM', re.DOTALL)
result = rgx_pat.findall(query)
```

And now `result` will be:

```
['a11.Column1\n, a12.Column2\n,SUM(Column3)']
```

I'm not sure whether you want `.*?` or `.*`, and whether you want to enforce whitespace after `SELECT` and before `FROM`, so I guessed at what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you @abarnert this is exactly what I was looking for. This was extremely helpful.